# How can I perform basic authentication while using JSON?

Tags: json, ruby, authentication

I would like to access to a website with a lot of information and display all of it (as of now). However, I want to use JSON.parse and also authenticate the user and password in order to extract that information.

This is what I have:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = 'http://robotrevolution.net/interface/int_order_options.php'
  uri = URI(url)
  response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  jsonVal = JSON.parse(open(response))
  puts jsonVal
```

However, while looking up online, I found I can use this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'


uri = URI('http://robotrevolution.net/interface/int_order_options.php')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
 :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', 
 :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

 request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
 request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'

 response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object

 puts response
 puts response.body
end
```

Moreover, I would like to find a way to mix both of them and use automatic authentication as well as parse JSON at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: Your title says "ruby on rails," but this doesn't look like Rails code. Are you using Ruby on Rails, or just Ruby?

Comment: I am on the .rb document, so I believe it is only Ruby. I am new on this, so I do not really know the difference haha.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RestClient library (https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).

Example:

```rb
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'ostruct'

url_endpoint = 'https://api.example.com'

basic_auth_user = 'user'
basic_auth_password = 'pass'
basic_auth_creds = "#{basic_auth_user}:#{basic_auth_password}"

response = RestClient.get(url_endpoint, {
  Authorization: "Basic #{Base64::encode64(basic_auth_creds)}"
})

json = JSON.parse(response.body, object_class: OpenStruct) unless response.empty?
```